# How to write a batch-file replacing all semicolons with commas in file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to replace in all *.txt files (located in one directory) one special character with another. In my case I would like to replace all semicolons which appear in the file with commas. Can you tell me how write a batch file, which will do it?
For example, I would like to replace line: 
1;2,3;4;5,6 with
1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Read the file line-by-line, replace the string, write each line to a new file, then replace the original file with the new file.

Comment: You should try superuser; this isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for you....

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims==" %%A in (input.txt) do set string=%%A & echo !string:;=,! >> output.txt
```

If......

input.txt

```
1;eggs;milk;bacon
2;bread;cakes;flour
3;salmon;pork;chicken
```

output.txt

```
1,eggs,milk,bacon
2,bread,cakes,flour
3,salmon,pork,chicken
```

Comment: It doesn't want to work. It writes a name of input file to the output file. if name of input file is input.txt and contains one line as: 1;egg;milk;bacon, then name of output file is output.txt but contains one line with input.txt

Comment: oh..my fault..I've corrected the code..check now.